# iOS ARCore - How to connect Android & iOS devices with ARCore and send and recive AR Objects?

Tags: android, ios, swift, arkit, arcore

I have explore an ARCore demo provided by Google which allows transferring the AR objects between Android & iOS devices.

How to achieve such things on iOS.

I have tried with Google's ARCore library and one ref. application "Just a line".

I think it's possible by using - ARKit (iOS), WebRTC & AR-Rendering.

If anyone having any idea with any third party library or any git source which could help me to achieve such features kindly provide those refs. here.

Explored URL : https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-ios-sdk
https://github.com/googlecreativelab/justaline-ios

Comment: Look at [Cloud Anchors](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/cloud-anchors/overview-android) but otherwise asking for tutorials/libraries is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Cloud Anchors API](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/cloud-anchors/overview-android)